# Contour Integral of $\frac{1}{1+e^z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration

How do I calculate $\displaystyle\int_{C_1(1)}(1+e^z)^{-1}\text{d}z$?

I have tried parametrizing $C_1(1)$ by $z=1+e^{i\theta}$ with $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$, but this does not help much as I would have a double exponential.
Any ideas on how to progress are welcome.

Comment: Google "Cauchy integral theorem."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That integral is equal to $0$, since the disk $D_\pi(1)$ is simply connected, the image of $C_1(1)$ is contained in it and the function$$\begin{array}{ccc}D_\pi(1)&\longrightarrow&\Bbb C\\z&\mapsto&\dfrac1{1+e^z}\end{array}$$is analytic.

I chose the disk $D_\pi(1)$ because, for each $z$ in that disk, $1+e^z\ne0$.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with this result, how come this works?

Comment: That's a standard Complex Analysis theorem: if $U$ is simply connected, $f\colon U\longrightarrow\Bbb C$ is analytic, and $\gamma\colon[a,b]\longrightarrow U$ is a closed path, then $\int_\gamma f(z)\,\mathrm dz=0$. It's a consequence of [Cauchy's integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem).

Comment: This is the [Cauchy-Goursat theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_integral_theorem) together with the fact that $1+\mathrm{e}^z$ is zero only on the odd integer multiplies of $\mathrm{i}\pi$.